# APNs no longer shares invalid token response (400/410 baddevicetoken) - Any workaround?

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Trying to improve my marketing automation tool's iOS app push delivery rates.
Unsubscribed/Uninstalls lead to a bunch of failures in a triggered App Push. FCM shares when the android device's push token is invalid. APNs stopped it. This helps in removing those tokens from the DB.

Any work around to it?

I can think of possible solution like - building a model to put a potential app-uninstalled-score to devices by consuming app activity/inactivity; to come up with a prediction if the devices potentially don't have the app anymore sounds viable?